# Tensorflow dequeue within while_loop

Tags: while-loop, tensorflow

consider this simple example:

```
l = [1,2,324,3,12,1,2,3]
q = tf.train.input_producer(l, shuffle=False)
x = q.dequeue()

t = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.int32, size=5, dynamic_size=True, clear_after_read=True)

_, t = tf.while_loop(cond=lambda i, a: tf.less(i, 5, name='less_op'),
body=lambda i, a: [i+1, a.write(i, [x])],
loop_vars=[0, t])
```

it outputs [1 1 1 1 1], since the dequeue() is called only once. Please tell me how to trigger the dequeue operation on each iteration.

Thank you!

Cheers, Kris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises because the [`tf.while_loop()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop) body captures the *value* 
of the tensor `x` as a loop invariant, whereas you want the *side effect* of dequeuing to be performed inside the loop.

The solution is to move the call to `q.dequeue()` inside the body, as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf

l = [1, 2, 324, 3, 12, 1, 2, 3]
q = tf.train.input_producer(l, shuffle=False)
t = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.int32, size=5, dynamic_size=True, clear_after_read=True)

# N.B. set `parallel_iterations=1` to ensure that values are dequeued in a
# deterministic FIFO order.
_, t = tf.while_loop(cond=lambda i, a: tf.less(i, 5, name='less_op'),
                     body=lambda i, a: [i+1, a.write(i, [q.dequeue()])],
                     loop_vars=[0, t],
                     parallel_iterations=1)

result = t.stack()

sess = tf.Session()
tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess)
print(sess.run(result))  # ==> '[[1], [2], [324], [3], [12]]'
print(sess.run(result))  # ==> '[[1], [2], [3], [1], [2]]'
```

Comment: Ok, so in case I use a reader (of any kind), I can just call reader.read(q) in the same spirit (instead of q.dequeue()). But what about using batches of data within the body? I can think of loading batches into a new queue, but this is a bit dirty. Is there another solution to this matter? Many thanks for your previous response anyway (: !

Comment: Yes, the same principle applies to any potentially-stateful op (like reading from a reader, or reading/writing a variable). For batches of data you could use `reader.read_up_to(n)`, and optionally pad the batch to full size (since `read_up_to()` can return a smaller batch if `n` doesn't divide the exact number of records in the file).

Comment: As always - very informative answer. As if you knew what my next question is going to be (: The last piece of the puzzle is: if there are _x_ records in my .tfrecords file and I call reader.read_up_to(y) with _y_ > _x_, am I going to become _x_ records, or is a subsequent file going to be dequeued? I think the former is the actual case, but the documentation just states: _Will dequeue a work unit from queue if necessary (e.g., when the Reader needs to start reading from a new file since it has finished with the previous file). It may return less than num_records even before the last batch._